# NARX PyNeurgen library

Tags: python, neural-network, time-series

I am trying to create autoregressive neural network (NARX) in Python. I just could find one library PyNeurgen. But I am not able to find any sample program to use it. To train and predict time series using the network. If anyone can share how to train and predict time series using network. Or if there is any other good library for NARX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check the tutorial:
http://pyneurgen.sourceforge.net/tutorial_nn.html
and You can find testcase here:
https://github.com/katerina7479/pyneurgen/blob/22e25c01469b3967360401196e7cd12dd5b00358/pyneurgen/demo/simple_network_with_graphs.py

```
...
from pyneurgen.recurrent import NARXRecurrent
...
#   NARXRecurrent
input_nodes = 2
hidden_nodes = 2
output_nodes = 2

output_order = 3
incoming_weight_from_output = .6
input_order = 2
incoming_weight_from_input = .4

net = NeuralNet()
net.init_layers(input_nodes, [hidden_nodes], output_nodes,
    NARXRecurrent(
        output_order,
        incoming_weight_from_output,
        input_order,
        incoming_weight_from_input))

net.randomize_network()
```

Comment: Can you provide an example for how to train and inference data using NARX as well?