# Example for NARX in python - both training and prediction

Tags: python, neural-network

Is there any end-to-end example of how to train *and* predict/inference data using a NARX model in python? 
There is the library PyNeurgen [NARX PyNeurgen library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40757117/narx-pyneurgen-library)
but the documentation for PyNeurgen isn't very complete.

This OP seems to have written a Keras implementation but, but the code is lacking an implementation for inferencing/prediction. [NARX implementation using keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087669/narx-implementation-using-keras)

Comment: btw, i did find this github repo for a sklearn compatible NARX implementation https://github.com/jxx123/fireTS . It does seem to lack some features but still better than PyNeurgen overall...

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for the equivalents of `model.fit()` & `model.predict()`, which are `net.learn()` and `net.test()` in [pyneurgen](http://pyneurgen.sourceforge.net/). Based on this [tutorial](http://pyneurgen.sourceforge.net/tutorial_nn.html) and this [example](https://github.com/rodrigoaraujo01/pet0305/blob/a84126d54927ff79138a28b38f9a6df60ca09c4c/tutorial_pyneurgen.py), I formulated this demo (in python 2.7) to give you an idea on how it is done. I hope it helps.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from pyneurgen.neuralnet import NeuralNet
from pyneurgen.recurrent import NARXRecurrent


def plot_results(x, y, y_true):
    plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
    plt.plot([i[1] for i in population])
    plt.title("Population")
    plt.grid(True)

    plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
    plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', label='targets')
    plt.plot(x, y_true, 'ro', label='actuals')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.legend(loc='lower left', numpoints=1)
    plt.title("Test Target Points vs Actual Points")

    plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
    plt.plot(range(1, len(net.accum_mse) + 1, 1), net.accum_mse)
    plt.xlabel('epochs')
    plt.ylabel('mean squared error')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.title("Mean Squared Error by Epoch")
    plt.show()

def generate_data():
    # all samples are drawn from this population
    pop_len = 200
    factor = 1.0 / float(pop_len)
    population = [[i, math.sin(float(i) * factor * 10.0)] for i in range(pop_len)]
    population_shuffle = population[:]

    all_inputs = []
    all_targets = []

    np.random.shuffle(population_shuffle)
    for position, target in population_shuffle:
        all_inputs.append([position * factor])
        all_targets.append([target])
        # print(all_inputs[-1], all_targets[-1])
    return population, all_inputs, all_targets 

# generate data
population, all_inputs, all_targets =  generate_data()

# NARXRecurrent
input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes = 1, 10, 1
output_order, incoming_weight_from_output = 3, .6
input_order, incoming_weight_from_input = 2, .4

# init neural network
net = NeuralNet()
net.init_layers(input_nodes, [hidden_nodes], output_nodes,
                NARXRecurrent(output_order, incoming_weight_from_output, 
                              input_order, incoming_weight_from_input))
net.randomize_network()
net.set_halt_on_extremes(True)

# set constrains and rates
net.set_random_constraint(.5)
net.set_learnrate(.1)

# set inputs and outputs
net.set_all_inputs(all_inputs)
net.set_all_targets(all_targets)

# set lengths
length = len(all_inputs)
learn_end_point = int(length * .8)

# set ranges
net.set_learn_range(0, learn_end_point)
net.set_test_range(learn_end_point + 1, length - 1)

# add activation to layer 1
net.layers[1].set_activation_type('tanh')

# fit data to model
net.learn(epochs=150, show_epoch_results=True, random_testing=False)

# define mean squared error
mse = net.test()
print "Testing mse = ", mse

# define data
x = [item[0][0] * 200.0 for item in net.get_test_data()]
y = [item[0][0] for item in net.test_targets_activations]
y_true = [item[1][0] for item in net.test_targets_activations]

# plot results
plot_results(x, y, y_true)
```

This results in the following plot:

[image]

For more examples, take a look at the following links:

- [Air_Quality_ppm_prediction/NARXImproved.ipynb](https://github.com/arooshitaneja/Air_Quality_ppm_prediction/blob/f4eece447a526421e4d3715db7f5143e22a4c738/NARXImproved.ipynb)
- [NARX-Prediction-Model/NARX_Neural_Network.ipynb](https://github.com/DimaVilda/NARX-Prediction-Model/blob/09e6f32ba6b5fc8e7f21c34ae0bd645403954d21/NARX_Neural_Network.ipynb)
- [CS230project/NARX_PyNeurGen.ipynb](https://github.com/gaoxuhua215/CS230project/blob/68964e01acbfd0f5aa230d8077b83f104dd09421/NARX_PyNeurGen.ipynb)
- [TimeSeriesNotes/narx.py](https://github.com/gmum/TimeSeriesNotes/blob/6982b9a077e88bbe13883ebaef48ea3561525a02/narx.py)

Comment: net.test seems to only evaluate the test data that is stored in the net object. I couldn't find any built-in method to do prediction on new data and return that data.

Comment: @SuperKogito - why do you cite an evolutionary model [Air Quality] above, which evolves in a rather **anti-pattern** fashion -- from poor into worse and into worst ( ever still growing MSE ) **predictive power** - i.e. showing bad, worse and worst errors as it predicts with poor, poorer and poorest results? Did I miss something cardinal there?

Comment: @user3666197 I only cited it as a rough example of how to use the `net.learn()` function but it might have not been the best example. @tete123f I further examined the docs and I agree to your point, I cannot find  any hints on how to run predictions on samples. The only idea that I came up with is to use the `net.set_all_inputs()` & `net.set_all_targets ` to pass new samples to the trained net and then try to use `net._evaluate()` or an edited version of it to return predictions but I wasn't successful. Maybe you have better luck with it.